# Typeahead.js Output a class from object to results

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, typeahead.js, typeahead

I'm using typeahead to pull suggestions from a database, via the code below, these are delivered as an array of objects and I'm pulling the first value into the suggestion then need the second to be output as a class around the result.

Like span class="flag-{val[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDLXF.png)}">Suggestion

Any help greatly appreciated.

```
$('#typeahead').typeahead(null, {
    source: function(query, process) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'source.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'query=' + query,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                var suggestions = [];
                $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                    var obj = {};
                    obj.label = val;

                    suggestions.push({ value: val[0] });
                    console.log( {value: val[0]}, {value: val[1]});
                });
                return typeof data == 'undefined' ? false : process(suggestions);
            }
        }); 
    }
});
```

[image: console log]

Comment: have you looked into custom templates on http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

Comment: @DaveBriand I have thanks - didn't quiet give me what I needed, have now figured out a nice simple solution though. Thanks

Comment: good to hear - i see your answer below.

Answer (score 0):

It struck me on the drive home from work that I could try this:

```
suggestions.push({ value: '<span class="flag flag-'+val[1]+'">'+val[0]+'</span>' });
```

and wouldn't actually need to complicate things by altering the typeahead templates. It works! :)

Further to this - adding the span markups into the input I've created a function to remove these...
        $(document).on('click keyDown :focus :active', '.tt-suggestion', function(e){
            cleanSuggestion ();
            e.preventDefault();
        });

```
    $(document).on('keydown', '.tt-input, .typeahead, .tt-hint', function(e){
        if(e.which == 38||e.which == 40||e.which == 13) {
            cleanSuggestion ();
        }
    });

    $(document).on('blur', '.tt-input', function(e){
        setTimeout(function(){
            cleanSuggestion ();
        }, 1);
    });     

    function cleanSuggestion () {
        var registeredValue = $('#registered-stallion').attr('value') 
        registeredValue = registeredValue.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
        $('#registered-stallion').attr('value', registeredValue);           
    }
```

for some reason the blur function would only work with a timeout as I couldn't see exactly where typeahead was reint its function here..

Comment: ah, except... the span pushes into the suggestion when clicked.

<span class="flag flag-it">frank</span>

Comment: you might want to look at creating a small templating engine and using that - ill post it in an answer so it can be formatted

Comment: Thanks @DaveBriand if you have time to mock up an example it'd be greatly appreciated, I've not had much luck with templating so far - probably missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I use underscorejs for templating, this adds the compile function to underscore. Typeaheadjs uses compile when it builds from templates.

```
_.compile = function(templ) {
    var compiled = this.template(templ);
    compiled.render = function(ctx) {
        return this(ctx);
    }
    return compiled;
}
```

As per the examples on the github page, you can now use templates.

Comment: Thanks Dave, unfortunately the templating is still going over my head. I've managed to strip the span tags before inserting all be it with a very hacky timeout on blur for that to work.  Updated my answer to show.